# How to read File using PDFReader

Tags: java, file, itext

I have a method `public void readFile(File inputFile, File outputFile)`, I want to read the File using `PDFReader`, but the reader reads only `String` values, I cant hardcode the string value because it is given by the user while exporting the file.

I used `FileUtils.readFileToString(inputFile)` but I get exception on the line `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);`

Kindly suggest a way to achieve this.

Code Snippet:

```
public void readFile(File inputFile, File outputFile){
String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(inputFile);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);

//some more code
}
```

Comment: append the exception in the question. when you say your code is not working then you have to provide a few things in question:
1) few lines saying what you are doing. 
2) shortest Code that is not working
3) Exception that is thrown
4) Sample input if any
5) Expected output if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the whole file to a string and passing to [PdfReader](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader-java.lang.String-) which is completely wrong. You need to pass *path of the file* or `File inputFile` itself.

You can try

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile.getCanonicalPath());//or inputFile.getName()
```

Or,

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
```

Comment: I get exception "com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found" at that line.

Comment: The file path may be wrong or you are giving a file which is not a PDF.
Try to print the `inputFile.getCanonicalPath()` and check for the file path.

Comment: The path name and File name are printing correctly Harish.

Answer (score 2):

The `PdfReader` class has different constructors. When you create an instance using a `String`, you are supposed to pass a *file path* (e.g. `myFolder/my.pdf`). What you are doing is **completely wrong!** You are reading a *binary file* into a `String`. That `String` is **not a file path!**

You can easily create a `PdfReader` instance using a `FileInputStream`.

It is unclear which version of iText you are using. Please make sure that you are using iText 7. In iText 7, `PdfReader` has the following [constructors](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.2/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html#constructor.summary):

- `PdfReader(InputStream is)`
- `PdfReader(InputStream is, ReaderProperties properties)`
- `PdfReader(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, ReaderProperties properties)`
- `PdfReader(String filename)`
- `PdfReader(String filename, ReaderProperties properties)`

If for some reason you need to use iText 5, then this is the [list of constructors you can use](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#constructor.summary):

- `PdfReader(byte[] pdfIn)`
- `PdfReader(byte[] pdfIn, byte[] ownerPassword)`
- `PdfReader(byte[] pdfIn, Certificate certificate, ExternalDecryptionProcess externalDecryptionProcess)`
- `PdfReader(InputStream is)`
- `PdfReader(InputStream is, byte[] ownerPassword)`
- `PdfReader(InputStream inputStream, Certificate certificate, ExternalDecryptionProcess externalDecryptionProcess)`
- `PdfReader(PdfReader reader)`
- `PdfReader(RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, byte[] ownerPassword)`
- `PdfReader(RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, byte[] ownerPassword, boolean partial)`
- `PdfReader(String filename)`
- `PdfReader(String filename, byte[] ownerPassword)`
- `PdfReader(String filename, byte[] ownerPassword, boolean partial)`
- `PdfReader(String filename, Certificate certificate, ExternalDecryptionProcess externalDecryptionProcess)`
- `PdfReader(String filename, Certificate certificate, Key certificateKey, String certificateKeyProvider)`
- `PdfReader(URL url)`
- `PdfReader(URL url, byte[] ownerPassword)`

As you can see, iText 5 is much messier than iText 7. We have completely rewritten iText from scratch to get rid of plenty of legacy classes and methods that were no longer relevant. The API of iText 7 is much more slick now.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read much more carefully through `PdfReader` constructors. Best way for your example is to wrap `File` into `InputStream`.

```
new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile))
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the update, I am using Itext5, below is the code snippet:

```
public void readFile(File inputFile, File outputFile){

    //i am reading the inputFile here

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);

    //doing some logic to manipulate the pdf and then saving the pdf to outputFile

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
}
```

//Then calling the readFile method in main class

```
private File showDialogBox(){

    if(getSelectedFile() != null){
        File inputFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        //JFileChooser in java swing
        //The selected File name will be given by the user before exporting it.
        readFile(inputFile, outputFile);  
    }
}
```